# c# KeyNotFoundException The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am pretty new to c# and I am trying to make a change to some code developed by somebody else that is a windows FE onto a SQL BE. I have this line of code:

```
flex_dataGrid1.Init(DbSpr.Spr["Position"], xh, true, null, new frm_Position_Modify());
```

Which, in other locations with a different variable for `positon`, works fine. As far as I can tell `position` is used to determine the stored procedure used to populate the dataset and I have created a new sp for this option.

When running the code get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in System.dll
>   {"The given key was not present in the dictionary."}

Can anybody shed any light on where I might be able to find the issue, or what other information you might need in order to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Somewhere in your code items are added to `DbSpr.Spr`. I dont have your code so I cannot tell you where. There must be an item added with the key `Position` or it will result in the exception you are seeing.

Comment: The error is on this field : DbSpr.Spr["Position"],  Spr is a dictionary and doesn't contain a key for the "Position".  The has to be an add to the dictionary for the key "Position" in your code before this line is executed.

Comment: This sounds like an endeavor that will not end well.

Comment: "*Can anybody shed any light on where I might be able to find the issue*". This happened to me before, too. It turns out that the issue is with the person who designed the system.

Comment: Thankyou, found the dictionary and that has solved the problem!